# cpanel php version update not changing in server

Tags: php, version, cpanel, shared-hosting, cloud-hosting

Hello Friends I am a beginner web developer don't know much about cPanel and hosting, I have been given a cPanel access by one of my friend the url of cpanel consists of ('**magnesium.cloudhosting.co.uk**'). So Now I have to update the php version of the server that is hosting the site, So Inside the cpanel dashboard, in ***software*** options I have an option called ***Select PHP Version***, then I go inside this option and change the php version to 7.0 (previously it was 5.6) and click on **set as current php version** button and save it. And now I go to ***server information*** option in cpanel and check the php version of the server and it shows 5.6, I tried to logout and login again but its not working. So What am I missing here.

Below is my cpanel dashboard snippet if you scroll down you will see there is an **software** option, inside which there is **Select PHP Version** option

[image: cpanel dashboard snippet]

Here is the inside look of **Select PHP Version** option

[image: select php version option]

Below is the snippet of server information you can see the php version is still 5.6.

[image: snippet of server information]

Please help me to update the php version I will provide more information If needed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the domain name I'm guessing that website is being hosted on a shared server? Lots of website hosts won't allow you to change PHP version for shared servers although I couldn't find a guide for your website host.

If you search for your website host + "change PHP version" you might find a step by step guide.

Answer (score 0):

On a shared hosting, you could try modifying .htaccess files to specify the PHP version that you want to use. On a dedicated server, you can follow these steps:

Login and search for "multiphp". Then click "MultiPHP Manager".
change php version in multiphp manager

Answer (score 0):

If you are choosing php8.1 then Run the following command

```
scl enable ea-php81 bash
```

Some other versions

```
scl enable ea-php74 bash
scl enable ea-php80 bash
scl enable ea-php82 bash
```

Note: this command will work only after changing the php version using php selector.